# Custom querystring-based routing in CodeIgniter or Phalcon

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, phalcon

I develop webapps for a relatively large enterprise.
In order to follow the company's security policy of only using obfuscated URIs, I usually use a homebrew framework using the front controller pattern.

Before obfuscation, the URIs come in this format:

```
domain.com/app_name/index.php?controller=A&action=B
```

The entire query string gets processed first when generating links to produce URIs in this format:

```
domain.com/app_name/index.php?q=Y29udHJvbGxlcj1BJmFjdGlvbj1C
```

where the value of `q` is `urlencode(base64_encode('controller=A&action=B'))`

The front controller will, on receiving a request, first decode the value of `q` and then set the parameters to `$_GET`, then the appropriate controller and action will be called based on that.

I'm about to start working on a new project and I want to try using a framework, either CodeIgniter (which I'm relatively familiar with) or Phalcon (which I would like to try). How do I implement this URI routing scheme in either framework? From my understanding both by default uses segment-based routing.

Comment: In Phalcon there is no such ability. Just nothing to add here :)

Why you even need this obuscation ? :O What's wrong with simple:

`domain.com/app_name/A/B` ?

Maybe perhaps something like `domain.com/app_name/Y29udHJvbGxlcj1BJmFjdGlvbj1C` with proper dispatcher events - but still - query routing is not possible in phalcon.

Comment: As I said, company security policy. I don't think it's secure at all, just discourages very casual tinkering, probably, but hey, I don't make the policies ;) how would I do `domain.com/app_name/Y29udHJvbGxlcj1BJmFjdGlvbj1C` ?

Comment: Route all routes like this to one action and then forward.